# Should a washing machine shutoff valve be replaced?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

I have Symmons washing machine shutoff valve like this:

[image]

My problem with it is that in order to  turn water on/off, I need to apply some force to the handle. It's not like I'm struggling much to do it, but it's  not running smoothly either. It's more force that I would of expected to apply in order to turn on/off.
It's also possible that it was not turned on/off for 4-5 years.

Does this problem happen with valves of this type and should I be concerned? Should I get a plumber to replace it or I can just use it while it's working?  Thank you!

Comment: Would place some lubricating oil on it.  Probably just sticking a bit and needs a little(a few drops) to unstick it.

Comment: @crip659. Thanks for the suggestion. I guess I would need to unscrew the handle to do it ?

Comment: Probably just need to open cover so can place oil on pivot pin and work handle back and forth a few times.